# Mixpanel track function not initialized - Not due to Page Ruler

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am new to Mixpanel, I have been trying to use the JavaScript library to track events but I am unable to do so.
I get -
*mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:13 Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.*

My code:

````
(function(f,b){if(!b.__SV){var e,g,i,h;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(e,f,c){function g(a,d){var b=d.split(".");2==b.length&&(a=a[b[0]],d=b[1]);a[d]=function(){a.push([d].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var a=b;"undefined"!==typeof c?a=b[c]=[]:c="mixpanel";a.people=a.people||[];a.toString=function(a){var d="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==c&&(d+="."+c);a||(d+=" (stub)");return d};a.people.toString=function(){return a.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking start_batch_senders people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split(" ");
for(h=0;h<i.length;h++)g(a,i[h]);var j="set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" ");a.get_group=function(){function b(c){d[c]=function(){call2_args=arguments;call2=[c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args,0));a.push([e,call2])}}for(var d={},e=["get_group"].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)),c=0;c<j.length;c++)b(j[c]);return d};b._i.push([e,f,c])};b.__SV=1.2;e=f.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=!0;e.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?
MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===f.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";g=f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];g.parentNode.insertBefore(e,g)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
 
import mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';
 mixpanel.init('MY TOKEN', {debug: true}, {api_host:"https://api.mixpanel.com"}, {loaded: function () {setTimeout(function () {mixpanel.track("Sign up");}, 1);}}); 

mixpanel.identify($email_address);
mixpanel.track("Sign up");
</script>```

I don't have the Page Ruler extension , which is given as the answer everywhere.
````